# Cannot Assign UIPickerView Delegate or DataSource

Tags: ios, swift, uipickerview, uipickerviewdatasource, uipickerviewdelegate

For some reason I cannot assign `UIPickerView`'s data source or delegate to my NSObject.

I have an `NSObject` which extends `UIPickerViewDataSource` and `UIPickerViewDelegate`

```
class STRepeatPicker: NSObject, UIPickerViewDataSource, UIPickerViewDelegate {

    let options = ["One", "Two", "Three", "Four", "Five"]

    func numberOfComponents(in pickerView: UIPickerView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, numberOfRowsInComponent component: Int) -> Int {
        return self.options.count
    }

    func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, titleForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int) -> String? {
        return options[row]
    }

}
```

And I have a `UIViewController` which attempts to set the data source and delegate. It is a `UIPickerView` inside a `UITableViewCell`.

I create the object at the top:

```
let repeatPickerDataSource = STRepeatPicker()
```

and then in `cellForRowAt:` I attempt to set the data source and delegate.

```
let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "pickerCell", for: indexPath) as! PickerTableViewCell

cell.picker.delegate? = repeatPickerDataSource
cell.picker.dataSource? = repeatPickerDataSource

return cell
```

When I run this it crashes, if I debug and attempt to print out cell.picker.delegate I get an error: `Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value`

Does anyone know how I can assign UIPickerViewDelegate and UIPickerViewDataSource to an NSObject like this?

Comment: Did you try set delegate in your PickerTableViewCell class?

Comment: Yes, I can do that, but I don't want to. I'm trying to keep the view as generic as possible, but be able to assign different data sources to different instances of the cell.

Comment: When you set picker.delegate in your PickerTableViewCell class. Is that work fine?

Comment: Yes it works fine without crashing

Answer (score 0):

The issue was that I was not registering my cell correctly, I was registering it as

```
self.tableView.register(UIPickerViewDelegate.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "pickerCell")
```

when it should have been this:

```
self.tableView.register(UINib.init(nibName: "PickerTableViewCell", bundle: nil), forCellReuseIdentifier: "pickerCell")
```